# Multiple Select in a row not working in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

When I am adding multiple Select in a row in Ionic 2 project it always takes the last select.
Any solutions.

Comment: Could you please add the most relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what have you tried so far, but this layout places two select components in the same *row*:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>

        <!-- Label -->
        <ion-label>Label</ion-label>

        <!-- First select -->
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="propertyOne">
            <ion-option value="0">Option 0</ion-option>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ion-select>

        <!-- Second select -->
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="propertyTwo">
            <ion-option value="0">Option 0</ion-option>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The key is to place both `ion-select` components inside of the same `ion-item`

Comment: Your code helped me finding out the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

I was using for loop to populate the select value in the following code.

```
<ion-item>
<ion-select placeholder="Minute" interface="popover [(ngModel)]="minute">
<ion-option *ngFor="let min of minList">{{min}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

The missing part was I did not add value.

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let min of minList" [value]="min">{{min}}</ion-option>
```

Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this one may be help for you:

<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
     <ion-col width-50>
        <ion-item>
           <ion-label>Minute</ion-label>
           <ion-select [(ngModel)]="below">
           <ion-option value="n12">2</ion-option>
           <ion-option value="n22">3</ion-option>
           </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col width-50>
        <ion-item>
           <ion-label>Minute 2</ion-label>
           <ion-select [(ngModel)]="inr">
           <ion-option value="h1">5</ion-option>
           <ion-option value="h2">6</ion-option>
           <ion-option value="h3" >7</ion-option>
           </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
     </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```